# How to make YouTube default to 2x speed when playing videos?

Tags: youtube

I know how to make it play at 2x, but how can I make the browser do it by default?

Comment: okay i've added question details to specify that i want youtube to make it the default option.

Comment: Okay - I've removed details about browser/OS specifications.

Comment: For hackers, there might be a possible solution via the youtube JS API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604934/html5-increase-youtube-speed-2x-from-url, perhaps in conjunction with a browser extension that always excutes the sample Javascript on youtube?

Answer (score 24):

If you are using Chrome, you can use *ImprovedTube* extension to make this happen. Followings are steps to achieve (tested):

1. Add the extension from the Chrome Web Store: [ImprovedTube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improvedtube-youtube-exte/bnomihfieiccainjcjblhegjgglakjdd)
2. Click on the extension icon and set Playback Speed to 2
3. Refresh YouTube if you've already opened it.
4. Enjoy!

Comment: Do you know if there is a FireFox analogue of ImprovedTube?

Comment: This also works for Opera

Answer (score 5):

I used an extension that allows me to change this via a script. I have been using [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/) myself, as it is open source, has an intuitive user interface and is available for Chrome, Opera, Firefox and others. There are also alternatives such as [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) and [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Youtube Playback Rate
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       *://youtube.com/*
// @match       *://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant       Any
// @version     1.0
// @author      Jason Miller
// @description 12/1/2019, 8:00:00 AM
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

sessionStorage.setItem("yt-player-playback-rate", JSON.stringify({
    "data": "2",
    "creation": Date.now(),
}));
```

The speed can be adjusted by changing the `"2"` after `"data"` to any value in the range 0.25–2.

Comment: still works today (20th apr 2020)

Comment: Still working in February 2022! I needed something to inject into an Electron/Nativefier app and this worked beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Video Speed Controller [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/android/addon/videospeed/?src=search) [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk) works on more sites than just YouTube, and with Preferred Speed (x) set to 2 and Remember Playback Speed checked, you need only press g if it's not at the speed you want (to temporarily go back to 1x and back again)